# Java Applet in .Net Web Application Issue

Tags: java, html, applet

How can I put a Java Applet in my .Net Web Application ?

I'm trying the following code

```
                        <applet code="com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain" 
                        archive="C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\SignedFingerprintSDKJava.jar, C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\SignedFingerprintSDKJavaAppletSample.jar, C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\sqljdbc4.jar" height="550" width="550">
                    </applet>
```

but i got the following error

```
   java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter.setProgressFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.setupProgress(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter.setProgressFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.setupProgress(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter.setProgressFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.setupProgress(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I insert into my .net project the .jar, occurs the error `IllegalArgumentException`, if I insert file:\ before the path of the jar files, occurs the error `SecurityException` like I said in comments.

Comment: could it be, that the .NET application thinks that C:\ (with "C") is the protocol you want to use? Maybe you should work with "file:\\C:\.." or you use an relative path from your execution directory

Comment: @lee.O With "file:\\C:\.." I got a SecurityException. Permission Denied file:\\C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\SignedFingerprintSDKJava.jar . If I went to Details of this error, appears the same that I posted. I provide all access to my C: but still the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java applet is configured using HTML tags, so reference to .Net is irrelevant here.

I guess that your problem is in manner you are configuring the classpath defined in attribute archive. The jar references specified there must be relative to your codebase. They cannot be absolute file paths on your machine.

You should write something like

`first.jar,second.jar`

and put the jars in place accessible over HTTP